# Laptop "Memory 1, Memory 2" meaning?

Tags: laptop, memory

I'm looking at buying a new laptop and have noticed some don't have a single memory description such as for example: **16GB DDR4 ...**

Some laptops I've seen have displayed:

---

Memory 1: Onboard 4GB DDR4 Memory

Memory 2: 16GB DDR4

---

What does this mean? Does the laptop have a full 20GB of memory? Or only 4GB unless I change some settings?

**Edit:**

This is the specific laptop I'm talking about:
http://store.acer.com.au/acer/store/index.php/notebook/travelmate-p648m-i7-8gb-512gb-ssd.html

Comment: The 4 GB is likely the graphics card memory, the 16 GB is likely the RAM.

Comment: @SirAdelaide Isn't it unlikely for graphics card memory to be DDR4?

Comment: Please post an example link or more details. Without some context it's impossible to guess what that means.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you tried to edit without logging in, so the "anonymous" edit got bumped to a review queue.  Just FYI.

Comment: The link specifically mentions "Memory 1 Onboard 4GB DDR4 Memory" and "Memory 2 16GB DDR4" Meaning they would add up to 20GB total.  The title also mentions "TravelMate P648-M, Intel Core i7, 20GB, 512GB SSD"  No to be rude but why is there a question when the title says "20GB", the description says "4gb & 16Gb"?  Nothing seems unclear unless in the real world its not usable or something.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of this laptop, Memory 1 (4 GB) is soldered to the motherboard, while Memory 2 (16 GB) is removable and upgradable.

[NotebookCheck](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Acer-TravelMate-P648-M-757N-Notebook-Review.167637.0.html) has details of the Travel Mate series, and includes the following:

> Memory: 8192 MB  DDR4-2132, Dual-Channel, one RAM slot (used), 4 GB soldered

and

> The underside of the computer features a maintenance hatch, which covers the single RAM slot and a hard drive bay.

[CNET](https://www.cnet.com/products/acer-travelmate-p648-m-777f-14-core-i7-6500u-8-gb-ram-256-gb-ssd-us-international/specs/) describes it a little more transparently:

> RAM: 1 x 4 GB + 4 GB (soldered)
>
> Installed Size: 8 GB
>
> Max Supported Size: 20 GB
>
> Slots Qty: 1

According to [DataMemorySystems](https://www.datamemorysystems.com/dms-memory/acer/travelmate-p648-m-53fa.htm) and [CNET](https://www.cnet.com/products/acer-travelmate-p648-m-777f-14-core-i7-6500u-8-gb-ram-256-gb-ssd-us-international/specs/), the slot can take up to a 16 GB ram stick, giving the laptop up to 20 GB total ram (4+16 GB). Some other versions come with 4 GB in the slot, the one you are looking at has RAM maxed out.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a description of the actual model there are two options:

1. One type of memory refers to the graphics card memory and the other to the system memory. I haven't seen any graphics cards with DDR4 memory but that doesn't mean they couldn't exist.
2. The laptop has 4GB of system memory soldered to the motherboard and has 16GB of system memory in a memory slot which you can remove and replace.